# Can I export a saved search from Kibana to Excel?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

How can I export data from saved search on Kibana to excel ? For visualization I could export them using export button available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like exporting a saved search is out of reach as of now according to this [ticket](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/4759).

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a way to export. Created a data table visualisation similar to saved search and could able to export them from there